# Samba/Linux File Permissions - Homes Not Writeable with 755

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, permissions, samba

Just upgrade to Ubuntu 12.XX LTS to 14.04.1 LTS.

My Samba server provides users the ability to write to their own directory by using the [homes] section.  After upgrading, they no longer have write access to their home directories through Samba.

I have created a test directory with their home directory with permissions of 777 or 775 and they can create files/directories in it that are owned by them.  If the permissions are 755 (which is my preference) then the user can't write to them.  Since the file are being created as the proper user, I assume that writes are also being attempted by the correct user.

I am trying to write files into directory /home/morris/junk/zz1
drwxr-xr-x 5 morris morris 4096 Nov 30 00:43 zz1

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

The relevent segments of my smb.conf are below.

```
[global]
log level = 3 acls:10
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
smb ports = 139 445
dns proxy = No
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d 
hosts deny = 192.168.1.4
veto files = Maildir/imap,Maildir
wide links = Yes
unix extensions = no
[homes]
hide dot files = yes
valid users = %U
read only = No
wide links = yes
writeable = yes
```

Comment: First of all check your log files. When accessing a file, it will tell you if you don't have write permissions. Also what kind of authentication do you use? Make sure user mapping between windows & linux is correct, otherwise you could be mapped as bad user and that could be the reason you have no write permissions when using 755. Finally you can try 'inherit acls = yes' in the homes section.

Comment: Thank you.  I did check the log files and I didn't see anything.  I know that mapping from Windows to Linux is correct, because the files are owned the correct user on the linux side.  I'll try "inherit acls" but it seemed like that acls may cause more issues than solve them.

Comment: What do you see in the logs exactly? When I check mine, I get something like:

[2014/12/16 09:47:53.233388,  5] ../source3/smbd/open.c:3012(open_directory)
  open_directory: opening directory /home/kyriacos.georgiou/blah, access_mask = 0x100081, share_access = 0x7 create_options = 0x1, create_disposition = 0x1, file_attributes = 0x10

If you examine the access mask and flags you will be able to see what are the write permissions.

Apologies for the late response.